# Let $A$ be a $4\times 4$ diagonal matrix whose entries are complex numbers such that $A^4=I$. If the trace of $A$ is zero then which is\are correct

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, complex-numbers, permutations

Let $A$ be a $4\times 4$ diagonal matrix whose entries are complex numbers such that $A^4=I$. If the trace of $A$ is zero then which is\are correct ($I$ is unit matrix)

(A) There are $36$ distinct matrices $A$

(B) There are $24$ distinct matrices $A$

(C) Number of possible values of determinant of $A$ is equal to $4$

(D) Sum of all possible values of determinant of $2A$ is equal to $0$

**My Approach:**

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} z_1 & 0 & 0 &0\\0 & z_2 &0 &0\\0&0&z_3&0\\0&0&0&z_4\end{bmatrix}$

then  $A^4=\begin{bmatrix} z_1^4 & 0 & 0 &0\\0 & z_2^4 &0 &0\\0&0 &z_3^4 &0\\0&0&0&z_4^4\end{bmatrix}$= $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 &0\\0 & 1 &0 &0\\0 &0 & 1 &0\\0& 0& 0& 1\end{bmatrix}$

Hence $z_1^4=z_2^4=z_3^4=z_4^4=1$ also trace of $A$ is zero i.e.  $z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4=0$

Possible cases are

**Case $1$:** $\{1,1,-1,-1\}$ and all the possible arrangement of $\{1,1,-1,-1\}$ i.e. $6$

**Case $2$:** $\{1,-1,-i,i\}$ and all the possible arrangement of $\{1,-1,-i,i\}$ i.e. $24$

**Case $3$:** $\{-i,i,-i,i\}$ and all the possible arrangement of $\{-i,i,-i,i\}$ i.e. $6$

Hence possible matrices are $36$ only.

Also possible values of determinat of $A$ are $\{1,-1\}$ i.e. $2$ possible determinant

Also sum of all possible determinant of $2A$ is zero

But Given answer is only $(a)$ but I'm getting $(a),(d) $

Note $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Thanks to @J.W.Tanner and @Sarvesh Ravichandran Iyer I've got to know that $b$ and $c$ and $d$ are incorrect

Comment: Aren't there more possible arrangements in case 2?  And how would you get determinant $\pm i$?

Comment: And the possible values of determinant of $A$ are affected by the fact that $z_1+z_2+z_3+z_4 =0$. For example, you cannot have $i$ or $-i$ as a determinant since every $i$ or $-i$ has to be cancelled out by $-i$ or $i$ respectively, so the product of those two terms ends up being a real number.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but whether (D) is true or not depends on whether the sum over values of the determinant is weighted (by the number of distinct matrices with that determinant) or unweighted.